# How can I use Firebug to check data if the page is reloaded?

Tags: html, ajax, debugging, firebug

How can I use Firebug to check data if the page is reloaded (in the case of AJAX, etc.)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep panel information by clicking the [Persist Button](http://blog.getfirebug.com/2009/07/24/firebug-1-5a19/) at the top of the panel, this will prevent it from clearing when a new page is requested.

Comment: Just a small correction that may help you understand what is going on: the Persist Button copies the content of the console panel from the deleted web page to the one that is created upon reload.  Each web page has its own console.